# extract column values based on comparing one column against multiple other columns

Tags: match, vlookup

I would like to compare the values of multiple columns from Table1, against values of columnA of Table2, if there's a match then create a new column in Table1 which will contains matched values from ColumnB of Table2.

My input is two Tables:

Table1

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| - | P2 | - | - | - | - |
| - | - | P3 | - | - | - |
| - | - | - | P4 | - |  |
| P1 | - | - | - | - | - |

Table2

| ColA | ColB |
| --- | --- |
| P1 | MSH3 |
| P2 | MSH5 |
| P3 | L6 |
| P4 | V5 |

THE OUTPUT IS ONE TABLE [see Col Output]:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | OUTPUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| - | P2 | - | - | - | - | MSH5 |
| - | - | P3 | - | - | - | L6 |
| - | - | - | P4 | - | - | V5 |
| P1 | - | - | - | - | - | MSH3 |

appreciate advice. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. In case someone has similar problem:

```
    Result = pd.DataFrame([])
    for i in DF1:
         Result = Result.append ( pd.merge(DF1, DF2, how = 'inner', left_on=i, right_on='ColA') )
```